# Does anyone know what this class$... or class$() mean in Java?

Tags: java

I'm refactoring some code and I've run into the following:

```
class$com$companyname$paymentservice$utility$TheClass == null ?
                    (class$com$companyname$common$crypto$TheClass = class$("com.companyname.common.crypto.TheClass")) : class$com$companyname$common$crypto$TheClass)
```

While I know what the ternary operator is supposed to do, I've never seen the definition of class like this or the calling of a method like this. Does anyone have any idea what this `class$` or even what the `$` is used for in Java?

Comment: It's part of the name of the class - my guess is that this is decompiled or generated code.

Comment: From the JLS section 3.8: "The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII dollar sign ($, or \u0024) and underscore (_, or \u005f). The dollar sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems. The underscore may be used in identifiers formed of two or more characters, but it cannot be used as a one-character identifier due to being a keyword."

Comment: @JonSkeet, no this is in the .java file.

Comment: looks like a compiled class (.class). Do you get this in debug mode or where exactly?

Comment: Generally dollar signs talk about **inner classes**, however that piece you've shared looks weird to me, too.

Comment: @NuAlphaMan: *"no this is in the .java file"* Right: As Jon said: A **decompiled** class file, or generated code. Either of which would be in a .java file.

Comment: Did you steal this code? Take your hands off the keyboard and remain still. The police will arrive soon.

Comment: @Kayaman LOL. Nope no stolen code, just trying to refactor some old code.

Comment: @Edwin, no this is not a compiled (.class) file. This is a class in a group of classes I need to refactor.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the clarification. Misread on my part.

Comment: It could also be generated code -- that is, code that wasn't typed by a human, but generated by a program so that it can be compiled by javac. This is common for parsers, for instance. Usually you would check in the original source (the language definition, for instance) but some people check in the generated code for... reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the class was generated by [RetroWeaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/).

It generates a method called `class$` inside the processed class which delegates to the real `Class.forName` method, and replaces all `SomeClass.class` with `class$("SomeClass")`.

The bits that don't quite add up:

1. I never understood how this worked in the decompiled output, because I have never seen said method in the output when the classes got decompiled.
2. You say you're looking at a .java file, so the actual `class$()` method must be somewhere in order to compile that at all, but also, RetroWeaver only works on class files, so it implies that someone processed the code through RetroWeaver and then decompiled it to produce their source code, which seems like an odd thing to do.